# Anaphrodisiac in Chinese?

Tags: translation

I have been searching the web and tried using Google Translate and have been unable to find the term for Anaphrodisiac.

According to Wikipedia Anaphrodisiac is something that reduces "sexual desire."

Comment: This term is not common because most people seek the opposite, that's why Viagra is so popular and the term for drug like that is so well known -- namely 壯陽藥  (aphrodisiac- Chinese medicinal term) or 春藥 (Chinese folk term for aphrodisiac) An-Aphrodisiac is basically anti- Aphrodisiac. . 'Anaphrodisiac  (medicine)' is most likely translated as a clinical term 性慾抑制(藥)

Comment: online dictionaries:  **ichacha** :  anaphrodisiac:adj.
平性欲的，制性欲的。
n.
平性欲剂，制性欲剂, **iciba**
    adj.

    制（性）欲的； 制欲剂；

    adj.

    制（性）欲的； 制欲剂；

Answer (score 3, accepted):

anaphrodisiac [ænˏæfrә`dIzIæk; ænˏæfrәˋdiziæk]

> <<形容詞>>adjective
>   抑制性慾(欲)的; 鎮慾(欲)的
>
> <<名詞>>noun
>   鎮慾(欲)藥; 制慾(欲)劑

[image]

Answer (score 0):

制欲剂
制慾劑

I don’t know if that’s a clinical term, but I’m doing what I can.